# Is isomorphism symmetric?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

It is from Jech's "Introduction to Set Theory." I think that symmetry doesn't follow from it, it has not been mentioned that the function $f$ is $onto$ (that it covers all $Q$).

If two ordered sets $(P, <)$ and $(Q, \prec)$ are isomorphic it doesn't mean that $(Q, \prec)$ and $(P, <)$ are isomorphic? There is no symmetry in this relation, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:** If $f\colon P\to Q$ is an isomorphism, what can you say about $f^{-1}$?

---

Edit: Note that the requirement is that the *range* of the isomorphism is $Q$. It is required to be onto $Q$.

Comment: The range of $f$ doesn't have to be all $Q$, so the domain of $f^{-1}$ might not be all $Q$. It follows from what I read in Jech's "Introduction to Set Theory."

Comment: @Graduate : The day isomorphisms will not become symmetric relations, I will kill myself. I mean, "iso" means "same". If "being the same as something else" is not reflexive, there's something wrong with the choice of words! I haven't read your book, but you should definitely give it a good look again!

Comment: @Graduate: You might be confusing "embedding" with "isomorphism".

Comment: @Graduate: You should add that information to your question, as it really changes the character of your query.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: I have uploaded a passage from the book, you can check it yourself.

Comment: @Graduate: Some people use "one-to-one" to mean what it actually says, rather than the common abuse of terminology to allow a mix of one-to-one and zero-to-one.

Comment: @Graduate: It is required to be surjective. It's just not spelled out. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: So to say that the range of a function is $Q$ means to say that $range(f) = Q$. I thought the author said literally that $f:P \longrightarrow Q$, which would mean just that $range(f) \subseteq Q$

Comment: @Graduate: No, $f\colon P\to Q$ requires that the range of $f$ is *a subset of $Q$*.

Comment: @Graduate : Typically in mathematics, whatever the book, if you read $f : P \to Q$, it is understood that $f(P) = \{ f(p) \in Q \, | \, p \in P \} \subseteq Q$. Personally I call $Q$ the range and $f(P)$ the *image*. I also dislike the use of the term "one-to-one" because of its ambiguity among different books ; injective, surjective and bijective maps are clearly defined terms which do not lead to confusion.

Comment: @Patrick: Most people call $Q$ the "codomain" of $f$, or don't call it at all. The range, at least in any context that I have met, was always synonymous to "image".

Comment: @AsafKaragila : Really??? Well that's one more reason for me to stop using this term... I just realized that I actually use the word codomain much more often than range.

Comment: @Patrick: Just don't kill yourself over this! :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila : Haha don't worry, I have faith that isomorphisms will remain symmetric relations for the rest of my happy life and I stand by my comment.

Comment: @Patrick: Well. Best of luck.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Just read in Mendelson's "Introduction to Topology" on page 13: "Let $f:A \longrightarrow B$ be given. $A$ is called the *domain* of $f$. $B$ is called the ***range*** of $f$."

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: (Read the previous comment.)

Comment: @Graduate: In my seven years of doing practically just mathematics, this is the first time I've seen this use. Perhaps 40 years ago it was somewhat more acceptable. Today I don't know anyone using this terminology on purpose.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : Perhaps the development of category theory has something to do with it.

Comment: @Patrick: Maybe. Maybe not. Who knows.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I was just reading *Strichartz*'s "The Way of Analysis" (not old, year 2000). On page 111 the author introduces functions and uses the word **range** when obviously talking about **codomain**. He writes: "We don't require that every point in *range* actually occurs as $f(x)$ for some $x$ in the domain." Instead of **range** (how we interpret it) he uses **image**.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I don't want to make too much of a point form it. But that passage from Jech's book I mentioned in my question is really confusing. And also you said you had never seen the word *range* used this way. Now you can no longer say it.

Comment: @Graduate: I can, because I have never really read a book of mathematics outside of set theory (of course I have flipped through many mathematical books, looking for references, or reading one small section or another, but I haven't systematically read a large portion of a book outside of set theory). This might very well be the convention in other fields, and I wouldn't know about this (and frankly, I don't really care). But Jech is a set theorists, and the book is in set theory. So that's that. If you will be so kind, flip back in Jech's book and find his definition for range.

Answer (score 0):

An isomorphism is defined as a bijective map. Intuitively, it is a way of saying that two sets are "equal," in a sense. There is a one-to-one (bijective) correspondence between the elements of each set. And as equality is symmetric (A=B if and only if B=A), so isomorphism is symmetric. Simply take the inverse of this bijective isomorphism between the sets, and you have another bijective map, another isomorphism. So yes, the isomorphism is symmetric.

Comment: An isomorphism is defined as an *invertible* map. Not all bijective morphisms are isomorphisms, although this will be true for some structures.